# 'proxy' config is set properly

Tags: javascript, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT4au.png)

npm i pdf-node
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://infyartifactory.ad.infosys.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/pdf-node failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND infyartifactory.ad.infosys.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-08-14T12_45_05_408Z-debug.log

-------------- RESOLVE THIS ERROR ?? ----------

I tried this code to execute in the vs code terminal, but getting above mentioned error!

npm i pdf-note

Answer (score 0):

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

By executing this command, the problem is resolved now